# Simple Web Page Navigation 'Previous Next' Php

Tags: php, web, pagination, jquery-pagination

I have 3 (.php) files/pages for a website (in a folder), I have Previous/Next Links displayed on the bottom of each. What php code on the previous/next link, would help me navigate to the next page.

For Example:

Lets say the pages are Page1.php, Page2.php, Page3.php, and I am currently on Page2.php.

If I want to click on the 'Previous' Link, I want Page1.php to be displayed.

If I click on 'Next' then I want Page3.php to be displayed.

I believe this is called 'pagination'?

Previous

Next

---

I dont know if this is possible. And I hope I have been clear with describing the problem.

Thanks,

babsdoc

Comment: Are there only ever going to be 3 pages? Or might you add more later and need to manage a next based on current page, rather than just if page is 2 next = 3 and previous = 1?

Comment: Yes James. I might add pages later. Which is why I need some code to seek the previous and next pages.

Comment: @babsdoc Here are a few tutorials on doing pagination: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/ and http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html and http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination and http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50803-simple-pagination/ and http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Pagination-Example-1_24.htm

Comment: Thanks Fred. Interesting. But I don't plan on using a database (mysql etc.). I just want the code to get the next and previous file in the folder (I am assuming Alphabetical sorting would be default).

Comment: @babsdoc You're welcome. However, this will prove to be rather difficult without using a DB, unless you find code that will do it using the [**scandir**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [**glob**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) functions. What have you tried?

Comment: js : window.history.go(-1); might be of some use. i guess u should use javascript send it a list of links

Comment: Googling Pagination PHP would do the trick then. Bad question.

Comment: @babsdoc TIP: Use the `@` symbol followed by my name, that way I know you're addressing me and sends me notification.

Comment: @metareviewr That's exactly how I got the URL's posted above for the OP.

Comment: @babsdoc This could work http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/virtualpagination.htm

Comment: Thanks @metareviewr bad or not, I needed help. Googling it is not a very helpful response.

Comment: @Fred I have a gallery script which I'm sure will do the trick for me without the DB. But, I'm messing it up trying to edit it. So wanted to know if there was a simple alternative I'm not aware of. The script scans the directory for all files and makes an array out of the list. I plan to use the elements from the array to somehow create the previous and next links.

Comment: But all you had to do was googling it or just search for your question here and you would have found the help you were looking for. We can't write a whole tutorial about PHP pagination just because you can't be bothered to make two searches on Google.

Comment: @babsdoc Funny you should mention a gallery script. Have a look at this URL, I think it may be do the trick: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/pagination-without-database-106465.html there are a few examples on that page. One of which will give you a problem though, underneath this line `print( "<hr>" );`
it shows `<br><br>");` you will need to just comment it out and will work.

Comment: @babsdoc You could post what you have for code also. Maybe I or someone else could have a look at it.

Comment: @metareviewr I request you to please ignore this post or report this post or something. I would rather have my problems than your angry-for-any-reason comments. I haven't directed this post specifically to you have I? And to assume I did this without googling it is like assuming I am some stone age fellow, innit? Thank you for all the help, and sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: @babsdoc Can you add it in your question instead?

Comment: @Fred I'm not a regular here. Pardon the silly mistakes I make. I usually google everything and make my stuff work ;)

Comment: @babsdoc It's ok, I understand. I'm a patient man. I have to be, I grow "cactus"... really lol

Comment: Thanks @Fred Would have a look over the weekend. Cactus?? Seriously? A token of appreciation, Whatever gives you the kicks :) 10 Most beautiful Cactii.... http://goo.gl/tzg2dQ

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the original code @Fred 

$images = "jars/"; # Location of small versions

$big    = "samp2/"; # Location of big versions (assumed to be a subdir of above)

$cols   = 2; # Number of columns to display

if ($handle = opendir($images)) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "samp2" && $file != "Thumbs.db") {
           $files[] = $file;
       }
   }
   closedir($handle);
}

foreach($files as $file)
{
$pc="Product Code:".substr($file,0,-4);

<a href=\"$images$big$file\" class=\"swap\"><img src=$images$file title=\"title\"
width=\"100\" height=\"100\">
$pc</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: If it's just a simple image pagination script you're looking for, then have a look at the link I gave you earlier, most of them in there work. http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/pagination-without-database-106465.html

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're going to keep a sane naming convention throughout (ie pageX.php), then the following should suffice.
(might not be the ideal solution for you but gives you an idea. Can be put in a function/changes made, etc)

```
$strCurrentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$strPattern = '/\d+/';
preg_match($strPattern, $strCurrentPage, $strGetPageNumber); // extract numerical value

//set two new vars to same as page number, increment one and subtract one
$strNextPageNum = $strGetPageNumber[0];
$strPreviousPageNum = $strGetPageNumber[0];
$strNextPageNum++;
$strPreviousPageNum--;

//set full filename with new numbers
$strNextPage = 'page'.$strNextPageNum.'.php';
$strPreviousPage = 'page'.$strPreviousPageNum.'.php';


//if file is found then show link
//next page
if (file_exists($strNextPage))
  {
    echo '<a href="'.$strNextPage.'">Next Page</a>';
  }
else
  {
    echo "No more pages";
  }

//previous page
if (file_exists($strPreviousPage))
  {
    echo '<a href="'.$strPreviousPage.'">Previous Page</a>';
  }
else
  {
    echo "No previous pages";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @James. Looks like I can madify and use this for my problem.